# Laravel - How to use session and route in config/services.php

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I working with facebook login in laravel 5 using `laravel/socialite`
But in many tutorials have to config in config/services.php like

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'abc',
        'client_secret' => 'def',
        'redirect' => 'http://ghi',
],
```

But i want dynamic them like user can input them and save to session like

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => session()->get('client_id'),
        'client_secret' => session()->get('client_secret'),
        'redirect' => route('aa'),
],
```

But session and route cannot use in config/services.php. How can i make it dynamic thank.

Answer (score 0):

`client_id` and `client_secret` are not for your users, but for your (facebook) app.

You need to have a developer account on facebook and create an app there. (No clue how, I'm not using facebook). Then you'll get a `client_id` and `client_secret` for that (facebook) app which you can add to `config/services.php`

Comment: Yep, it for my fb app, but i ant input it dynamic?

Comment: Why do you want to make it dynamic? It doesn't ever change.

Comment: I want setup them on my website

Comment: Again, `client_id` and `client_secret` are not for your users!